# Restricted stocks

Tags: united-states, stocks, rsu

I have a 36,000 shares of a $0.30 stock. The company is still in business and is listed. The stock certificated is stamped restricted. I contacted the company to remove the restriction & was told the records were lost for 2001 when is was issued. So the restriction can not be removed. I asked for a replacement issue of stock was told he couldn't or wouldn't do it because of no records. He told me to put it in a picture frame. What to do?

Comment: You're asking "What to do?" but haven't told us what you're trying to accomplish. Do you want to sell the stock? transfer it?

Comment: Also, what *is* the restriction? It should say on the certificate...

Comment: Put it in a picture frame?

Comment: File a complaint with the SEC: https://www.sec.gov/oiea/Complaint.html